# Find Selected Value of asp.net Radio Button Control by its class using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net

I am currently working with a radio button control defined as:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbQ2" CellSpacing="10" runat="server" class="rbQ2"
CssClass="radioButtonList" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table"
onclick="javascript: SetQ2DetailVisibility();">
    <asp:ListItem>Yes</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>No</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

I am using a function to disable/enable detail data based on the selected value of the radio button.  When I use the client id as the selector to find the selected value of the radio button, the variable "value" is assigned "yes" or "no" depending on the Selected Value of the radio button:

```
function SetQ2DetailVisibility() {
    var value = $("#<%=rbQ2.ClientID%>").find(":checked").val();
    if (value == "Yes") {
        ShowQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
    else {
        HideQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
}
```

However when I use the class attribute as the selector, value is assigned "undefined":

```
function SetQ2DetailVisibility() {
    var value = $(".rbQ2").find(":checked").val();
    if (value == "Yes") {
        ShowQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
    else {
        HideQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
}
```

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't assigned a value to the ListItems. You are trying to compare the text.

Try this:

```
function SetQ2DetailVisibility() {
    var value = $("#<%=rbQ2.ClientID%>").find(":checked").text();
    if (value === "Yes") {
        ShowQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
    else {
        HideQuestionDetail("#q2detail");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The webforms' implementation of RadioButton actually creates a span next to the radio button, which is where the text is placed.  Thus, you'd need to grab the next sibling span and pull the value there.

You can continue using your code if you add the value as a value attribute to your listitems:

```
<asp:ListItem Value="Yes">Yes</asp:ListItem>
```

Alternatively, you can do it this way (the inner content is used as the `Text` attribute, anyway):

```
<asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
```

`Value` is the value submitted to the server, `Text` is what is shown to the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem(v=vs.110).aspx